# What is the purpose of Underscore.lua module in Lua?

Tags: lua

In some source code  I saw the usage of "[Underscore.lua](https://mirven.github.io/underscore.lua/)" module.

```
_ = require 'underscore'
```

The description says the following:

> `Underscore.lua` is a Lua library that provides a set of utility
>   functions for dealing with iterators, arrays, tables, and functions.
>   It's api and documentation are heavily inspired by `Underscore.js`.
>   It is idiomatic in Lua to use the underscore character for throw away variables so you can simply assign it to another variable name...

The examples provided in the docs are a bit confusing to me. For example, what is the purpose of the below operation?

```
_ = require 'underscore'
_.each({1,2,3}, print)

1   1   {
  1 : 1
  2 : 2
  3 : 3
}
2   2   {
  1 : 1
  2 : 2
  3 : 3
}
3   3   {
  1 : 1
  2 : 2
  3 : 3
}
```

It is clear that this module provides some functions for iterators ,arrays etc. But why use `_` when you can just use any other character that is  more visible than an underscore? Especially when many editors do not highlight it and it makes pretty cumbersome to read. I don't quite understand what's all the fuss.

Comment: Yes, Lua allows Morse-style programming: `_.__:_()` due to underscore character being pretty valid in Lua identifiers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> But why use _ when you can just use any other character that is more visible than an underscore?

*ahem*:

> heavily inspired by Underscore.js

Because that's what [Underscore.js](http://underscorejs.org/) used.

I rather suspect that the underscore character was chosen precisely *because* it is not terribly visible. The point of these utilities is that you can use them anywhere, that they're day-to-day things that you need for basic manipulation of data structures.

As such, they should appear to be standard functions available in the language, with minimal syntax needed to access them. But you can't just dump them into the global table/namespace/etc; that might conflict with existing code. So you give them the absolute minimum of syntax needed to access them.

Comment: In my understanding, [it's pretty idiomatic](http://lua-users.org/wiki/LuaStyleGuide) to use the underscore for variables in loops that are ignored, like in `for _,v in ipairs(t) do print(v) end`. Therefore, the underscore IMO is not a very safe choice here.

Comment: @ThomasW: That may be the case in Lua, but again, Underscore. ***js***.

Comment: That's of course right, but we're talking about a Lua module here, and even though it's named "underscore", I'd probably prefer loading it under a different name.

Answer (score 3):

If you use

```
your_favorite_variable = require 'underscore'
```

you can use

```
your_favorite_variable.each({1,2,3}, print)
```

but the underscore (except it has the same name as the library and the referenced javascript library) has several advantages:

- Easy and fast to type. Therefore quite accessible when you need it
- Not visible. You don't want to have it visible if you want to consider it as part of "standard" library

This is quite common approach. Similar is used for jQuery in Javascript, which is misusing `$` the same way.